# (Type) safely retrieving an element of a vector

Tags: haskell

I am attempting to write a function

```
getColumn :: Int -> Vector n e -> e
```

that retrieves the i'th item from a vector of size `n`.

These vectors are defined as follows:

```
data Natural where
  Zero :: Natural
  Succ :: Natural -> Natural

type One   = Succ Zero
type Two   = Succ One
type Three = Succ Two
type Four  = Succ Three

data Vector n e where
  Nil  :: Vector Zero e
  (:|) :: e -> Vector n e -> Vector (Succ n) e

infixr :|
```

Is there some way to write the `getColumn` function in a way where the compiler will reject the code if the `Int` is too big for the `Vector`'s size?

How would I write this function?

Comment: What would you expect to happen if the `Int` is unknown to the compiler, e.g. derived from user input?

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam Using `Int` was probably incorrect. I guess I'm looking for some way to use the `Succ` type to mean less than or equal to. I can make the `Vector` non-empty by writing, `Vector (Succ n) e`, but I have no idea how to represent `<=`.

Comment: @sdasdadas: we can actually safely index by Int-s too, I edited my answer to include that.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First, we need a *singleton* type for the naturals. Singletons are run-time representations of type-level data, and they're called singleton types because each of them has only a single value. This is useful because it establishes a one-to-one correspondence between the values and the represented type; just knowing either the type or the value lets us infer the other.

This also lets us circumvent the limitation that Haskell types cannot depend on Haskell values: our types will depend on the *type index* of a singleton, but that type index can be in turn determined from the *value* of the singleton. This somewhat tortuous detour is not present in fully dependent programming languages such as Agda or Idris, where types can depend on values.

```
data SNatural (n :: Natural) where
    SZero :: SNatural Zero
    SSucc :: SNatural n -> SNatural (Succ n) 

deriving instance Show (SNatural n) -- requires StandaloneDeriving
```

We can see that for any `n`, `SNatural n` has only a single possible value; it just mirrors the original `Natural` definition.

There are multiple ways we can proceed towards vector indexing.

#### 1. Defining the `<` constraint directly.

Defining `<` on naturals is straightforward:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators, TypeFamilies #-}

type family a < b where 
    Zero   < Succ b = True
    a      < Zero   = False
    Succ a < Succ b = a < b
```

Now we can express boundedness with a type equality constraint:

```
index :: ((m < n) ~ True) => Vector n a -> SNatural m -> a
index (x :| xs) SZero     = x 
index (x :| xs) (SSucc i) = index xs i
index _         _         = error "impossible"

main = do
    print $ index (0 :| 1 :| Nil) SZero -- 0
    print $ index (0 :| 1 :| Nil) (SSucc (SSucc SZero)) -- type error
```

#### 2. Using an alternative representation of naturals with baked-in bounds.

This is the standard solution in dependently typed programming, and IMO the simpler one, although it's a bit more difficult to understand at first. We call the bounded natural type `Fin n` (for "finite"), where `n` is a natural representing the upper bound. The trick is to index our number in a way such that the size of the value can't be greater than the index.

```
data Fin (n :: Natural) where
    FZero :: Fin (Succ n)
    FSucc :: Fin n -> Fin (Succ n)
```

It's apparent that `Fin Zero` doesn't have any values. `Fin (Succ Zero)` has a single value, `FZero`, `Fin (Succ (Succ Zero))` has two values, and thus `Fin n` always has `n` possible values. We can use it for safe indexing straightforwardly:

```
index :: Vector n a -> Fin n -> a
index (x :| xs) FZero     = x
index (x :| xs) (FSucc i) = index xs i
index _         _         = error "impossible" 

main = do
    print $ index (0 :| 1 :| Nil) (FSucc (FSucc FZero)) -- type error
```

#### Addendum: using the `singletons` library and doing safe indexing by `Int`-s.

As we've seen, doing dependent programming in Haskell involves a hefty amount of boilerplate. The type-level data and their singletons are more or less identical, yet still need separate definitions. The functions operating on them have to be duplicated similarly. Luckily, the `singletons` package can generate the boilerplate for us:

```
{-# LANGUAGE 
    TypeFamilies, GADTs, DataKinds, PolyKinds,
    ScopedTypeVariables, TemplateHaskell #-}

import Data.Singletons.TH

-- We get the "SNat n" singleton generated too. 
$(singletons[d| data Nat = Z | S Nat |])

data Vector n e where
  Nil  :: Vector Z e
  (:|) :: e -> Vector n e -> Vector (S n) e
infixr :|

data Fin n where
    FZ :: Fin (S n)
    FS :: Fin n -> Fin (S n) 

index :: Vector n a -> Fin n -> a
index (x :| xs) FZ     = x
index (x :| xs) (FS i) = index xs i
index _         _      = error "impossible"
```

The package also includes convenient ways to generate singleton values from types as needed:

```
foo :: SNat (S (S (S Z)))
foo = sing
```

`sing` is a polymorphic value that may serve as a stand-in for any singleton value. Sometimes the correct value can be inferred from the context, but other times we have to annotate its type index, usually using the ScopedTypeVariables extension.

Now we can also index safely by `Int`-s without being overmuch bothered by boilerplate (not a *catastrophic* amount of boilerplate though; implementing `sing` for `Nat` by hand would require one more typeclass and a couple of instances).

In general, verified programming is not about validating data compile time (as we've seen in the examples above), but rather about writing functions that operate in a provably correct way, even on data that is unknown compile-time (you could say that it's irrelevant *when* we validate the data, provided that the validation functions are correct). Our `index` can viewed as a semi-verified function, because it is *impossible* to implement an error-throwing version of it that typechecks (modulo bottoms and divergence).

To safely index by `Int`-s, we just have to write a verified conversion function from `Int` to `Fin`, and then use `index` as usual:

```
checkBound :: Int -> SNat n -> Maybe (Fin n)
checkBound i _ | i < 0 = Nothing
checkBound 0 (SS _)    = Just FZ
checkBound i SZ        = Nothing
checkBound i (SS n)    = case checkBound (i - 1) n of
    Just n -> Just (FS n)
    Nothing -> Nothing
```

Again, the magic of `checkBound` is that it is impossible to write a definition that returns a `Fin` that violates the given bound.

```
indexInt :: forall n a . SingI n => Vector n a -> Int -> Maybe a
indexInt v i = case checkBound i (sing :: SNat n) of
    Just i  -> Just (index v i)
    Nothing -> Nothing
```

Here we need to utilize some `singletons` machinery: the `SingI` constraint allows us to conjure up an appropriate singleton value using `sing`. It's a harmless class constraint, because *every* possible `n` is an instance of `SingI`, by construction.

Comment: Classic answer, as of 53 minutes ago.

Comment: what and how is preventing GHC from allowing a less convoluted definition of all this; something nicer such as what's in Idris and Agda?

Comment: @ErikAllik GHC was around well before we had a good enough idea how to do dependent typing. GHC Core was extended incrementally over a long time, starting from plain System F; arguably switching to a dependent core language now would both simplify the implementation and increase power, but it's a major change. It's being considered and researched though; see [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O805YjOsQjI) and [this link](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/DependentHaskell) for details.

Comment: That's exactly the kind of answer I wanted to get; thanks a bunch!  It's very nice to hear that there are some plans to introduce DT into GHC so we wouldn't have to forever salivate at Agda and Idris.